# how to change a websites functionality for return users

Tags: javascript, html, caching, web-applications

I am researching for a small site/app that i will be developing soon. I want to have an intro in a header at the top of the landing page but I dont want you to see it every time you come to the site, only the first.

After the site has been visited once, is there a way to start the user further down the page,   or hide the header by using cache or something.

I am comfortable with most front end development, if someone could just point me in the right direction on what i should use or do i would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to set a cookie on first visit.  If the cookie is set, do whatever it is you want to do.

If this setting is something that needs to be long living and not annoy the users, I would implement something server side, e.g. Authentication and saving the preference.

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to persist these days...

- `localStorage()`
- cookie
- cookie-like hacks
- server-side

If this *intro* could be annoying for repeat users and the site has a login, I'd persist it server side. You don't want the user being hit with it when they use a different browser or computer to access your site.

If not, use `localStorage()`.